# Have to refresh page with HTML5 offline

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, offline

I have written a HTML5 offline Application.
It works alright so far, but I have to refresh some pages to make them run right.

1. For example a network site:
   The page is noted in the manifest file under NETWORK:.
   I can access it, when I am online, when I go offline, it is still running,
   even if I refresh the index.html.
   Just if I refresh the network site, I shows me, that I'm offline.
2. A site that stores values (localstorage):
   When I reach the site from index.html the stored values won't be shown.
   After refresh the site runs like it should.
   For the Link of the index.html I tried "data-ajax='false'" and "rel='external'".
   This worked while online, but it didn't work when I was offline.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok first question seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5127143

Comment: Can you post some code? I'm not experienced with the app cache, but it seems to me that you are trying to detect when you are online/offline. That is, as far as I understand, not the intention. But let's focus on the second question. "When I reach the site from index.html ..." Do you mean that you first load the page and the refresh to make it load your locals? Seems really strange.